# Ejecutar proyecto Java con Spring en CMD

Tags: java, netbeans, spring

Estoy realizando un proyecto en Java con Spring que me reciba un nombre como parámetro y lo muestre al usuario, el proyecto que estoy generando es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para verificar que estuviera correcto el proyecto agregué un hola mundo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este hola mundo se ejecutó bien desde Netbeans y desde el cmd mostrando el mensaje, salvo un detalle que al ejecutarse no muestra las dependencias de Spring según el tutorial que vi, solamente me muestra el mensaje.

En mi computadora lo muestra así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el tutorial lo muestra así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El proyecto me compila sin errores en Apache Netbeans 11.3.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al no poder ejecutar correctamente el proyecto desde el cmd, no puedo levantar la página web ya que el servidor no reconoce la ruta de mi controlador.

```
package umg.edu.gt.webapp.controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

/**
 *
 * @author MasterAlienware
 */
@RestController
public class IndexController {
    @GetMapping("/api")
    public String Saludo(@RequestParam String nombre){
        return "Hola Sr." + nombre;
    }
}
```

El archivo pom.xml tiene los siguientes datos:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>umg.edu.gt</groupId>
    <artifactId>webapp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>webapp</name>
    <description>Demo</description>
        <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>                                        
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

No se que pueda ser lo que me hace falta, si es algo que debo instalar en la computadora o es algún problema del proyecto en sí. Si pudieran ayudarme a esclarecer mi duda por favor, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usted comentó la línea que tiene **"SpringApplication.run"**, sin esto no iniciará el framwork de Spring.

Por otro lado puede apoyarse del comando `mvnw.cmd` para ejecutar comandos maven y compilar, instalar dependencias etc. O iniciar con el apoyo de este comnando la aplicación spring, con el comando `mvnw spring-boot:run`.

Si es la primera vez que ejecuta el proyecto también puede ejecutar `mvnw install` el cuál instalará todas las dependencias al mismo tiempo que compilará la aplicación, luego de este comando también puede usar `java -jar target\webapp2-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` para inciar la aplicaciòn.